# Delete JS Script with a JS Script

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to disable a script via a script. For example. Within my blogging platform I have the following added by default..

```
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/@tryghost/portal@latest/umd/portal.min.js" data-ghost="https://www.packetflow.co.uk/"></script>
```

Is there a way to delete this or remove via javascript?

Comment: Have you tried to scan the page's DOM and remove it? or maybe rename the source file to something else?

Comment: Why do you need to remove it via JavaScript?  If it's your webpage, can't you just remove it from the source?

Comment: is it actually added *like this* to the HTML? your blog doesn't minify and pack all the scripts together before serving?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a certain level of ambiguity to this question or maybe i am just overthinking things.

**Removing the Element from the DOM**

```
var scriptElement = document.querySelector('script[data-ghost="https://www.packetflow.co.uk/"]').remove();
```

This removes the Script element from the DOM but, **if the script runs and affects elements before this line is run, ITS EFFECTS CANNOT BE UNDONE.**
...
Since the script has a **defer** attribute, you could always make sure that your script with the remove line is located above it.

**Removing the EFFECTS of the script**

As aforementioned, this cannot be done after the script has been executed **UNLESS** you know eXactly what the script has affected in the DOM and are willing to reverse those effects with a countering script of your own.